# how to go from http to https for external IP address on Google Cloud ubuntu vm

Tags: r, wordpress, https, google-cloud-platform, shiny

I'm using Google Cloud Platform compute engine vm, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. It has a static IP address. I have successfully launched shiny R hello sample web app on the vm (port 3838), and I can access this shiny R web app through an iframe my website hosted on WordPress.com. However, the web app through port 3838 remains http which causes some display problems due to security on the WordPress site. I also have nginx successfully loaded and the index page (https://www.takir-analysis.org) does load as https. How do I get the static external IP address for the vm to be secure https?

Please advise on how to make this connection https.

My shiny R app web page : http://35.239.19.123:3838/

My WordPress page, see 2nd iframe (check browser block if shiny R app does not display) : https://takir.org/project-information/

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can You see this Special configurations for VM instances

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NGINX deployed, [use it as proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html).

If your nginx is on another VM, install it on your VM and do the same thing.

In NGINX configuration, you can set a certificate for TLS security.

Comment: Okay, so if I set up NGINX as a proxy for the Shiny app, this will make the Shiny app pages secure? NGINX is on the VM and that is what's currently serving https://www.takir-analysis.org. I used certbot for that. So making NGINX the proxy for the Shiny app would then make http://www.takir-analysis.org:8383 to HTTPS?

Comment: I followed the instructions to run Shiny with a proxy here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy

takir-analysis.org:8383 still does not come in as HTTPS. Is there something I could be missing that's not on this page?

Comment: No, you have to reach NGINX port and, according with your configuration, NGINX will route your request to your app. NGINX often listen on port 80 and 443 by default

Comment: I copied the shiny sample app files over to /var/www/ . https https://takir-analysis.org/shiny.html comes in but the shiny app pages show "403 Forbidden"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the **403** please execute:

```
sudo chmod 644  /var/www/html/*
```

Then to redirect all traffic from http (:80) to https (:443), edit this file:

```
vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

And add:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

As is explained here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/best-way-to-configure-nginx-ssl-force-http-to-redirect-to-https-force-www-to-non-www-on-serverpilot-free-plan-by-using-nginx-configuration-file-only